# Having issues with compiling node.js from source using ./configure

Tags: compiling, make, node.js

I referred to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324261/configure-no-such-file-or-directory-even-after-installing-build-essentials) already answered question, but it wasnt of any help. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

I'm trying to install node.js on my Debian 8.0. According to this github [article](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installation#building-on-linux), I followed. I have the tarball file downloaded, extracted it, but when I tried to run `./configure` inside the extracted tarball directory, it said

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I've checked the per-requisites that the site gave, I had all of them installed. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: `configure` script doesn't exist? `ls configure` what's the output? If it exists and if you are not able to run then add executable permission to that file. `chmod +x configure`. If the configure doesn't exist at all then run `autoreconf -v -f --install` and then run `.\configure`. Better send your source tree structure.So that I can see what is missing.

Comment: i've added the screenshot. see the edit

Comment: ls configure says no such file or directory

Comment: `root@shazLaptop:~/Downloads/node-v4.1.1-linux-x64# ls configure
ls: cannot access configure: No such file or directory

root@shazLaptop:~/Downloads/node-v4.1.1-linux-x64# autoreconf -v -f --install
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required

root@shazLaptop:~/Downloads/node-v4.1.1-linux-x64# .\configure
bash: .configure: command not found
`

Comment: That's not the proper sources. Looks like you have compiled data.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of your screenshot, it looks like you downloaded the pre-compiled binaries. If that's the case, you won't have to compile anything. You should find an executable `nodejs` file inside the `bin` folder.

If you want to compile your own, you should download the source tarball [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.1.1/node-v4.1.1.tar.gz) instead of the binary tarball.

Comment: i have `node` and `npm` file in the bin directory. How do i use it? If i run `./node` and then run the command `node -v` to check the version of node installed, it says node is not defined

Comment: That works!! thanx!!! i was literally wasted my time to find this solution. then realized how stupid i am..

Answer (score 1):

Extract and copy the folder somewhere. for ex :

```
/home/your_username/packages
```

or somewhere else you want.

Your path should look like: `/home/your_username/packages/node-v5.7.1`

Then add the node path to your `$PATH` so that u can execute node from anywhere

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/your_username/packages/node-v5.7.1/bin
```

That's it!

To check, execute this command:

```
node -v
```